# Install latest setuptools on a system level

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

When creating a virtual environment, activating it and looking at the version of setuptools...

`virtualenv test`

`source ./test/bin/activate`

`pip list`

it shows:
`setuptools (0.9.8)`

After, I'm upgrading the version of setuptools by running `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, but i don't want to do that every time.

I want the latest version of setuptools to be installed on the system level when creating a virtual environment. How do I make that work?

Comment: Wait. You want to install a global dependency when activating a virtualenv? I'm not really sure I understand completely, could you elaborate?

Comment: Seems like your version of `virtualenv` is pretty old - maybe update that instead?

Comment: Yes, so whenever I create a virtualenv, it will automatically add the latest setuptools version

Comment: I tried updating virtualenv, but it doesn't fix the issue. I need to change the global dependency somehow

Comment: Then first check if `pip` is really the env's `pip`: `source test/bin/activate && which pip` should return `test/bin/pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `setuptools` the same way but outside any virtual environment and with superuser privileges:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```